# Store Hours: Display Current Time and Holidays

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm working to add store hours to a particular site. I found this great bit of JS that displays the current time when the page loads and identifies whether or not the store is closed. However, I would like to change the time captured at time of page loading to an active clock. I'm hoping someone can assist.

When the page loads, it displays the time at which the page loads. i.e. Visit site at 12:30PM, timeDiv displays 12:30PM. At 12:31PM, it still displays 12:30PM.

What I would like instead is an active clock, so that at 12:31PM it displays 12:31PM and displays the current time at each interval after that.

Here's the link to the original Pen: https://codepen.io/zeinab92/pen/xwWGWM

```
var now = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var checkTime = function() {
  var today = weekday[now.getDay()];
  var timeDiv = document.getElementById('timeDiv');
  var dayOfWeek = now.getDay();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();

  //add AM or PM
  var suffix = hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";

  // add 0 to one digit minutes
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes; }

  if ((dayOfWeek === 1 || dayOfWeek === 2 || dayOfWeek === 3 || dayOfWeek === 4 || dayOfWeek === 5) && hour >= 9 && hour === 17 && minutes <=29) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
    timeDiv.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + ' - we\'re open!';
    timeDiv.className = 'open';
  }

  else if ((dayOfWeek === 6) && hour >= 8 && hour === 15 && minutes <= 59) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);
    timeDiv.innerHTML = '<p id="hour">it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '</p> <p id="stat">we\'re open!</p>';
    timeDiv.className = 'open';
  }

  else {
    if (hour === 0 || hour > 12) {
      hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
    }
    timeDiv.innerHTML = '<p id="hour">It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '</p><p id="stat">we\'re closed!</>';
    timeDiv.className = 'closed';
  }
};

var currentDay = weekday[now.getDay()];
var currentDayID = "#" + currentDay; //gets todays weekday and turns it into id
$(currentDayID).toggleClass("today"); /hightlights today in the view hours modal popup

setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
checkTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very popular library for JavaScript called momentjs and it handles a lot of date/time logic nicely.  I'd recommend you start there.

This code extends momentjs in much the same way you'd need to put into your holidays:

https://gist.github.com/jrhames/5200024

The basic logic is to track your holidays in a separate custom array then create a function that takes a date as a parameter and does a lookup into your array of holidays.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I'm still working to modify it. The problem is that in each instance that I adjust the checkTime() function, the clock disappears.

The holidays are a bonus. I just really need to sort out that the clock is active while the user is on the page.

Thanks for the tip, again.

Comment: I think you need to add more details about that to your question to get a good answer.

Comment: When the page loads, it displays the time at which the page loads.

i.e. Visit site at 12:30PM, timeDiv displays 12:30PM. At 12:31PM, it still displays 12:30PM.

What I would like instead is an active clock, so that at 12:31PM it displays 12:31PM and displays the current time at each interval after that.

Comment: Please add that to your Question, it will get lost down here in the comments